# CONTAINS unhappy with char(13)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why won't `SSMS` process this script for me?

```
DECLARE @containsReturn AS CHAR(500) = 
'ME@ME.co.uk; 

YOU@YOU.co.uk;'


CREATE TABLE #x(ProblemColumn CHAR(500));
INSERT INTO #x VALUES(@containsReturn);

SELECT * FROM #X;


UPDATE  #x 
SET     ProblemColumn = REPLACE(ProblemColumn, char(13), '')
WHERE   CONTAINS(ProblemColumn, CHAR(13))
```

I get this error, focused on the final `CHAR(13)` in the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CHAR'.

Comment: it's `chr(13)` i think....

Comment: You do know contains is a with full text search?  That column is full text indexed?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin your comment is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick thing why you even care where clause in this case, just run the update statement like this

```
UPDATE  #x
SET     ProblemColumn = REPLACE(ProblemColumn, char(13), '')
```

it will do the right thing. it will perform better too

Comment: No that will not perform better.  It will take a lock on every row.

Comment: @Blam my table is very small and used rarely so @mannyyysh answer works fine. Moreover it saves on the overhead of adding a `FT-index`.

Comment: @whytheq - Congrats, you've chosen the worst solution given.

Comment: @whytheq If it is a small table then why did you have the where in the first place?

Comment: @Blam I got that code from a different article that I forgot to reference (but will) thanks again for the help - this particular Q&A has helped solve a mysterious bug that has been around for a couple of months.

Comment: @whytheq I am cool with not getting the check.  But when you accept an answer someone else with the same problem at your level may assume it is the proper answer.  It is not the proper answer and makes a false statement.  I did not mark it down.

Answer (score 6):

Because the TSQL [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) method takes a `NVARCHAR` as the second parameter and it cant implicitly convert `CHAR(13)` so you need to declare it as a variable which can be:

```
DECLARE @srch NVARCHAR(1) = CHAR(13)
UPDATE  #x 
SET     ProblemColumn = REPLACE(ProblemColumn, char(13), '')
WHERE   CONTAINS(ProblemColumn, @srch)
```

Incidentally, when you do this, you just get another error:

> Msg 7601, Level 16, State 2, Line 15
>   Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view '#x' because it is not full-text indexed.

If your real table is not a temp table, and really is Full-Text indexed, you'll be fine. Otherwise you could just do something much simpler:

```
UPDATE  #x 
SET     ProblemColumn = REPLACE(ProblemColumn, char(13), '')
WHERE   ProblemColumn LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE  #x 
SET     ProblemColumn = REPLACE(ProblemColumn, char(13), '')
WHERE   CHARINDEX (char(13), ProblemColumn) > 0;
```

The where eliminates taking a lock of every row.

CHARINDEX is not fulltext.  If you were using fulltext just for this then don't.

If you are literally inserting values like that then

```
INSERT INTO #x VALUES(REPLACE(@containsReturn, char(13), ''));
```

It eliminates the update altogether

And if you are clearing out char(13) why not also clear out char(10)?

Comment: +1 thanks for the efficiency improvement on mannyyysh's answer

Comment: WHERE clause should be WHERE   CHARINDEX (char(13),ProblemColumn) > 0;

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10) = CHAR(13)
UPDATE  #x 
SET     ProblemColumn = REPLACE(ProblemColumn, @A, '')
WHERE   ProblemColumn LIKE '%@A%'
```